# Condition for null value in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, null

When I am displaying my array by using var_dump I get the following result:

```
 array(1) { [0]=> NULL }
```

I want to apply a condition that when my array has a null value it should do something. I have tried using array[0]== NULL and array[0]= NULL inside my condition but it does not work. Can anyone tell me what could be the correct condition for it?

Comment: `if(is_null($array[0])) {}`? By the way, `==` makes a comparison, `=` is an assignement (even in an `if` statement).

Comment: `if(in_array(NULL, $yourArray){}`

Answer (score 5):

PHPs [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) checks if a variable doesn't exist or has a falsey value (like `array()`, `0`, `null`, `false`, etc).

```
<?php
if (!empty($array[0])) {
  echo "Not empty";
} else {
  echo "empty";
}
 ?>
```

or by using [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
<?php
if(is_null($array[0])) {
  echo "empty";
} else {
  echo "not empty";
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if($array[0] === NULL) {
echo "empty";
} else {
echo "not empty";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by several ways:

```
if(is_null($array[0])) {}
```

or

```
if(!isset($array[0])) {}
```

or

```
if($array[0] === null) {}
```

By the way, `==` makes a comparison, `=` is an assignment (even in an `if` statement) and `===` compares values *and* type.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have error in syntax because of `$` in Anik's answer. He just updated his answer. lol.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr =  array();
if (!empty($arr)){
   //do your code
}
else {
  echo "Hey I'm empty";
}
```

Comment: This would tell if whole array is not empty or not. I don't need this.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Is this your are expecting Marium?    $arr = array ( 
      0 => 5, 
      2 => NULL, 
      3 => 'prabha', 
      'k' => "NULL", 
      'l' => NULL, 
      'm' => 'money'
    );
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
      if ($val==NULL) {
        echo 'null is : ' . $key . ' => ' . $val . "<br>";
      }
      else {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $val . "<br>";
      }
    }